# Constructer function's method not working

Tags: javascript

I have written the following code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
    <h1 id="para"></h1>
    <script>                
        function Dice(sides) {  
            this.sides = sides; 
            this.roll = function() {                                            
                var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * this.sides) + 1;
                console.log(randomNumber);
            }                       
        }

        var dice = new Dice(6);
        var dice10 = new Dice(10);
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

When I check the console, it's not printing random numbers & it seems my 'roll' method is not working. If I write code without roll method, it's working. But I want to enhance my skills in JS, so I am curious to know what's the problem with roll method in my constructor function.

Comment: Because you are not calling the function, just defining it.

Comment: Side note: "Dice" is plural. A single one of them is called a "die".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to *call* your `roll` function:

```
var dice = new Dice(6);
dice.roll();
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to call method of object after instantiation:

```
dice.roll();
dice10.roll();
```

You does not see `roll()`s result after call of constructor, because constructor defines method, not calls it (in your case).

Answer (score 0):

Add line

```
dice.roll();
```

or

```
dice10.roll();
```

at the end.

The problem is you defined the constructor, but didn't call roll.